# Prove that if a ≡ b(mod m) and c ≡ d(mod m), then a − 2c ≡ b − 2d(mod m)

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, modular-arithmetic

I'm having trouble trying to do a proof for this problem:

a ≡ b(mod m) and c ≡ d(mod m), then a − 2c ≡ b − 2d(mod m)

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Where are you having trouble? Did you start your proof with what the congruence hypotheses mean? Have you written down what would make the congruence conclusion true? Show us some work and we may help you.

Comment: We have $m|a-b$ and $m|c-d$ implying $m|(a-b)-2(c-d)=a-2c-(b-2d)$

Comment: Here’s the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** A good first step to *any* proof is writing down what the definitions say for the hypotheses used and for the desired conclusion.  In this case the hypotheses are $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$ and $c\equiv d\pmod{m}$.

By *definition* these mean that there exists some integer $j$ and some integer $k$ such that

$$(a-b)=jm$$

and

$$(c-d)=km$$

We wish to reach the conclusion $a-2c\equiv b-2d\pmod{m}$, which is to say we wish to show that there exists some integer $l$ such that

$$(a-2c)-(b-2d)=lm$$